# É possível escrever sempre na primeira linha usando PHP?

Tags: php

Bom, eu quero fazer com que o PHP sempre escreva na primeira linha em um arquivo de texto, ou seja, quero que ele nunca escreva em baixo ou em seguida no texto.

Simplificando, quero que ele escreva antes dos textos.

É possível?

Comment: É possível sim, o que est´[a fazendo, tem alguma dúvida específica. Você pode [edit] a pergunta e colocar seu código e onde está tendo problema.

Answer (score 2):

Sim é possível, mas não há um comando específico, se é isso que quer saber.

```
file_put_contents($filename, $data . file_get_contents($filename));
```

Não esquece de colocar a quebra de linha: `$data = 'Belezura\n';`

Comment: Esse  método consome bastante memória, mas em alguns casos é  mais rápido. Essa resposta oferece uma alternativa se estiver lidando com arquivos muito grandes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3332403/1840019

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja isso que deseja fazer:

```
$nome_arquivo = 'c:\texto.txt';
$arquivo      = file($nome_arquivo);
$arquivo      = implode("\n",$arquivo);
$string_a_ser_inserida = "PROPRIEDADE DE : PABLO MARTINS" . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($nome_arquivo , $string_a_ser_inserida . $arquivo);
```